# Customize the KnpMenuBundle

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

**How to customize KNPMenuBundle?**

I can't figure out how to add an image or a span tag using the KnpMenuBundle.

I simply want this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
         <img src="{{asset('bundles/mybundle/images/my_image.png')}} /">
         <span>My Title</span>        
     </li>
</ul>
```

In the MenuBuilder, this would start with:

```php
$menu->addChild('My Title');
```

How could I add the image in the `<li>` statement?

---

### EDIT: THE EASY WAY

There is actually an easy way to do this within the bundle:

**<kbd>1</kbd>**  **Copy the template** `vendor\KnpMenu\src\Knp\Menu\Resources\views\knp_menu.html.twig`
into your `Acme\AcmeBundle\Resources\views\Menu\knp_menu.html.twig` and extend it as follow:

```html
{% extends 'knp_menu.html.twig' %}
```

**<kbd>2</kbd>**  **Modify the template** according to your needs. For example, if you decide to add a span tag each time you use  `$menu->addChild('Your Title');`, simply add the span tag between `<a></a>`:

```html
{% block linkElement %}
    <a href="{{ item.uri }}"{{ _self.attributes(item.linkAttributes) }}>
        <span>{{ block('label') }}</span>
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

**<kbd>3</kbd>**  **You can now choose your custom layout** when using the menu:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'template': 'AcmeBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig'}) }}
```

Comment: Why not define an attribute of the `<li>` or `<span>` element and add the image in css ?

Comment: "The Easy Way" listed above is awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to put the "knp_menu.html.twig" in the "app/Resouces/views" directory. This doesn't work. What can be the mistake ?

Comment: As @DARSC0D3 have said in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21887674/1284485), you need to import the parent template to get the attributes working.

Comment: In addition to copying the template as above, one must also modify `config.yml` such that the `template:` line in `knp_menu:` block reads `YourBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig`.

Comment: Following your instructions ends up with `Unable to find template "AppBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig"`. BTW I up-voted your answer for the time you spent on providing this tutorial

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CSS works for this case, but sometimes you might need to add or change the markup more significantly. For that you can use a custom renderer as defined here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_renderer.md

An example of a bundle that does this is the [MopaBoostrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle) I've highlighted the important parts here.

The service definition where the `knp_menu.renderer` tag is added:

```
services:
    mopa_bootstrap.navbar_renderer:
        class: Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Navbar\Renderer\NavbarRenderer
        arguments: [ @service_container, [] ]
        tags:
            # The alias is what is used to retrieve the menu
            - { name: knp_menu.renderer, alias: navbar }
```

and the twig template can be written like so, for example.

```
<div class="navbar {{ (navbar.hasOption('fixedTop') and  navbar.getOption('fixedTop')) ? 'navbar-fixed-top' : '' }}">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container{{ (navbar.hasOption('isFluid') and navbar.getOption('isFluid')) ? '-fluid' : '' }}">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            {% if navbar.hasOption('title') %}<a class="brand" href="{{ path(navbar.getOption('titleRoute')) }}">{{ navbar.getOption('title') }}</a>{% endif %}
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                {{ navbar.hasMenu('leftmenu') ? knp_menu_render(navbar.getMenu('leftmenu'), {'currentClass': 'active', 'ancestorClass': 'active', 'allow_safe_labels': 'true'}) : '' }}
                {% if navbar.hasFormView('searchform') %}
                    {%- set form_view = navbar.getFormView('searchform') -%}
                    {%- set form_type = navbar.getFormType('searchform') -%}
                    {%- set form_attrs = form_view.vars.attr -%}
                    {% form_theme form_view _self %}
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-{{ form_attrs.pull|default('left') }}" method="{{ form_attrs.method|default('post') }}" action="{{ path(navbar.getFormRoute('searchform')) }}">
                    {{ form_widget(form_view) }}
                    </form>
                {% endif %}
                {{ navbar.hasMenu('rightmenu') ? knp_menu_render(navbar.getMenu('rightmenu'), {'currentClass': 'active', 'ancestorClass': 'active', 'allow_safe_labels': 'true'}) : '' }}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks MDrolette, this answer helped me a LOT! Your guidance was really helpful! I have done something very similar to what you recomended except that I only extended the template knp_menu.html.twig in this case. I have edited my question in case you are interested. Again, awesome reply. Cheers :-)

Comment: Is there a full example of how to have a working custom renderer? https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/custom_renderer.html I have followed this but still doesnt help.

Answer (score 6):

I spent a while figuring this out.

There is an parameter you can apply when defining the menu item called 'safe_label'. By setting this to true it output the image in the navbar instead of the html.

```
    $image = "<img src='/path/to/image' />";
    $menu->addChild( $image , 
      array(
        'route' => 'url_route_name',
        'extras' => array(
          'safe_label' => true
        )
      )
    );
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Correct, but you should also use raw format when you render bundle, like: {{ knp_menu_render('main',{'template':'AcmeBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig',{'allow_safe_labels': true})|raw }}

Comment: A minor amendment to @repincln 's life saver suggestion: the correct syntax as of symfony 2.8 is `{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'template': 'AcmeBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig', 'allow_safe_labels': true})|raw }}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the macros from the parent template before you can use them.

```html
{% block linkElement %}
    {% import 'knp_menu.html.twig' as knp_menu %}
    <a href="{{ item.uri }}"{{ knp_menu.attributes(item.linkAttributes) }}>
        <span>{{ block('label') }}</span>
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

**To simply add classes and other HTML attributes** (for example, to integrate the menù with Twitter Bootstrap addind its classes and IDs), you can use the methods provided for that sort of customization.

Here are some useful resources:

- **Here are all the details from KNP Menu Bundle's documentation: [Creating Menus: The Basics - Menu attributes](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/doc/01-Basic-Menus.markdown#menu-attributes)**
- **Here are some concrete examples: [(On GitHub) KNP
  Menu Bundle with Bootstrap 3 and Font Awesome 4](https://gist.github.com/nateevans/9958390)**

KnpMenuBundles provides some documented methods like setAttributes, selLinkAttirbute or setLabelAttribute (and other methods too) that are useful to customize the menù rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define an attribute of the `<li>` or `<span>` element and add the image in css ?