# Specify current route or template as active link KnpMenu

Tags: symfony, menu, knpmenu

In symfony2, as describe above, I want to set the specified menu child as active status in Controller or Template, how can I achieve that? That is to say, I want several routes (controller action, template) map to one menu child, is that possible? I guess I could get the menu in controller or template and set it to active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already implemented when using **KNPMenuBundle**. Classes are automatically generated for `first` `last` and `current` elements.

---

Your menu will automatically look like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="first">
        <a href="/whatever1">Menu Level 1</a>        
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="/whatever2">Menu Level 2</a>        
    </li>
    <li class="last">
       <a href="/whatever3">Menu Level 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Assuming that you use Menu builder this way:

```php
//src/Acme/YourBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php
public function createSimpleMenu(Request $request)
    {
        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
        $menu->setCurrentUri($request->getRequestUri());

        $menu->addChild('Menu Level 1', array('route' => '_route_whatever1'));
        $menu->addChild('Menu Level 2', array('route' => '_route_whatever2'));
        $menu->addChild('Menu Level 3', array('route' => '_route_whatever3'));

        return $menu;
    }
```

---

Therefore, you need to apply the css to `current` instead of `active`.
As you can see, the job is realised by `$menu->setCurrentUri($request->getRequestUri());`.

If you wish to customize manually your menu (*in your case, you want to have several routes that map to the same element*) you can use a switch statement:

```php
//src/Acme/YourBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php
public function createSimpleMenu(Request $request)
{
// YOUR MENU AS USUAL FIRST
// ...
// A SWITCH IF YOU WISH TO CUSTOMIZE MANUALLY
switch($request->get('_route')) {
    case "_route_whatever1bis":
        $menu['Menu Level 1']->setCurrent(true);
        break;
    case "_route_whatever2bis":
        $menu['Menu Level 2']->setCurrent(true);
        break;
    case "_route_whatever3bis":
        $menu['Menu Level 3']->setCurrent(true);
        break;
    }
return $menu;
}
```

**Note:** To customize the way KNP Menu Bundle renders your menu, override `knp_menu.html.twig`. You can see the procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226963/customize-the-knpmenubundle).

Comment: your way is great, but the phrase

$request->get('_route')

just return "_internal" as result, how could I actually get the requesting route name?

Comment: This topic is related to your [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2). See carignan.boy reply.