# Unable to override KnpMenuBundle template

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

With `...MyBundle\Resources\views\Menu\knp_menu.html.twig`, deleting the `</li>` has no effect on the rendered menu.  (Removing the tag is done to remove the space between inline list elements.)  I have followed the advice provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226963/customize-the-knpmenubundle), including the `{% import 'knp_menu.html.twig' as knp_menu %}` mentioned toward the bottom of that post.  Is this because `knp_menu.html.twig` already extends `knp_menu_base.html.twig`? Or what?

#### layout.html.twig:

```
...
{{ render(controller('VolVolBundle:Default:userMenu')) }}
...
```

#### userMenuAction:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$tool = $this->container->get('vol.toolbox');
$type = $tool->getUserType($user);
return $this->render(
                'VolVolBundle:Default:userMenu.html.twig', array('type' => $type)
);
```

#### userMenu.html.twig

```
...
{% if type is not null %}
    {% set menu = "VolVolBundle:Builder:"~type~"Menu" %}
    {{ knp_menu_render(menu) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you please add source code that you use - in your template, in place where you output menu?

Comment: @SpiRi7: Code added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found deep [in here](https://github.com/knplabs/knpmenubundle/issues/68). All that's required to do a global override of the template is to modify `config.yml`.

#### config.yml:

```
...
knp_menu:
    twig:  # use "twig: false" to disable the Twig extension and the TwigRenderer
        template: VolVolBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig
...
```